# C programming traffic game

Tags: c

How could i utilize a generic linked list and struct to keep track of player movement and car location for ”undo feature”? This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SPACE 0
#define ROAD 1
#define CAR 2
#define PLAYER 3
#define GOAL 4

#define CAR_EAST '>'
#define CAR_NORTH '^'
#define CAR_SOUTH 'v'
#define CAR_WEST '<'

int **map;
int rows, cols;
int playerRow, playerCol;
int goalRow, goalCol;
int carRow, carCol;
int carDirection;

typedef struct Node
{
    int playerRow;
    int playerCol;
    int carRow;
    int carCol;
    int carDirection;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node *head = NULL;

// Function to insert a new state into the linked list
void insertStart(int playerRow, int playerCol, int carRow, int carCol, int carDirection)
{
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->playerRow = playerRow;
    newNode->playerCol = playerCol;
    newNode->carRow = carRow;
    newNode->carCol = carCol;
    newNode->carDirection = carDirection;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

// Function to remove the first node from the linked list
void removeStart()
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    Node *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
}

// Function to undo the last move
void undoMove()
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return; // Nothing to undo
    }

    // Restore previous state
    playerRow = head->playerRow;
    playerCol = head->playerCol;
    carRow = head->carRow;
    carCol = head->carCol;
    carDirection = head->carDirection;

    // Remove the state from the linked list
    removeStart();
}

void loadMap(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(file, "%d %d", &rows, &cols);

    map = (int **)malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        map[i] = (int *)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &map[i][j]);
            if (map[i][j] == PLAYER)
            {
                playerRow = i;
                playerCol = j;
            }
            else if (map[i][j] == CAR)
            {
                carRow = i;
                carCol = j;
                carDirection = CAR_EAST;
            }
            else if (map[i][j] == GOAL) /* Set goal position */
            {
                goalRow = i;
                goalCol = j;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int checkWinCondition()
{
    if (playerRow == goalRow && playerCol == goalCol)
    {
        return 1; /* Player reached the goal */
    }
    return 0;
}

int checkLoseCondition()
{
    if (playerRow == carRow && playerCol == carCol)
    {
        return 1; /* Player collided with the car */
    }
    return 0;
}

void printMap()
{
    char object;
    system("clear");

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == rows - 1 || j == 0 || j == cols - 1)
            {
                map[i][j] = '*';
            }
            switch (map[i][j])
            {
            case SPACE:
                object = ' ';
                break;

            case ROAD:
                object = '.';
                break;
            case PLAYER:
                object = 'P';
                break;
            case CAR:
                switch (carDirection)
                {
                case 0:
                    object = CAR_NORTH;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    object = CAR_EAST;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    object = CAR_SOUTH;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    object = CAR_WEST;
                    break;
                default:
                    object = CAR_EAST; /*Initial direction*/
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case GOAL:
                object = 'G';
                break;
            default:
                object = '*';
                break;
            }
            printf("%c", object);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /* Prints user guide on terminal */
    printf("Press w to move up\n");
    printf("Press s to move down\n");
    printf("Press a to move left\n");
    printf("Press d to move right\n");
    printf("Press q to quit game\n");
}

void enableBuffer()
{
    struct termios term;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);
}

void disableBuffer()
{
    struct termios term;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
    term.c_lflag |= (ECHO | ICANON);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);
}

void movePlayer(char direction)
{
    int newPlayerRow = playerRow;
    int newPlayerCol = playerCol;

    insertStart(playerRow, playerCol, carRow, carCol, carDirection);

    switch (direction)
    {
    case 'w':
        newPlayerRow--;
        break;
    case 's':
        newPlayerRow++;
        break;
    case 'a':
        newPlayerCol--;
        break;
    case 'd':
        newPlayerCol++;
        break;

    case 'q':
        break;

    default:
        printf("Invalid input. Use 'w' to move up, 's' to move down, 'a' to move left, 'd' to move right and 'q' to quit the game.\n");
        sleep(1);
        break;
    }

    if (newPlayerRow >= 0 && newPlayerRow < rows &&
        newPlayerCol >= 0 && newPlayerCol < cols &&
        map[newPlayerRow][newPlayerCol] != CAR &&
        map[newPlayerRow][newPlayerCol] != '*')
    {
        if (map[newPlayerRow][newPlayerCol] != ROAD)
        {
            map[newPlayerRow][newPlayerCol] = SPACE;
        }
        map[playerRow][playerCol] = SPACE;
        playerRow = newPlayerRow;
        playerCol = newPlayerCol;
        map[playerRow][playerCol] = PLAYER;
    }
}

void moveCar()
{
    int newCarRow = carRow;
    int newCarCol = carCol;

    insertStart(playerRow, playerCol, carRow, carCol, carDirection);

    switch (carDirection)
    {
    case 0: /* Going Up */
        newCarRow--;
        break;
    case 1: /* Going Right */
        newCarCol++;
        break;
    case 2: /* Going Down */
        newCarRow++;
        break;
    case 3: /* Going Left */
        newCarCol--;
        break;
    }

    /* When haven't reach the end of path then proceeds*/
    if (newCarRow >= 0 && newCarRow < rows &&
        newCarCol >= 0 && newCarCol < cols &&
        map[newCarRow][newCarCol] == ROAD)
    {
        map[carRow][carCol] = ROAD;
        carRow = newCarRow;
        carCol = newCarCol;
        map[carRow][carCol] = CAR;
    }

    /* Check if right and left path is able to proceed, if not, change direction of car according to direction of path*/
    else
    {
        int leftDirection = (carDirection + 3) % 4;  /* Turning 90 degrees counter-clockwise (left turn). */
        int rightDirection = (carDirection + 1) % 4; /* Turning 90-degree clockwise turn (right turn). */

        int leftRow = carRow; /* Update car row for to left route */
        int leftCol = carCol; /* Update car column for to left route */

        int rightRow = carRow; /* Update car row for to right route */
        int rightCol = carCol; /* Update car column for to right route */

        /* Handles direction when car goes to left path */
        switch (leftDirection)
        {
        case 0:
            leftRow--;
            break;
        case 1:
            leftCol++;
            break;
        case 2:
            leftRow++;
            break;
        case 3:
            leftCol--;
            break;
        }

        /* Handles direction when car goes to right path */
        switch (rightDirection)
        {
        case 0:
            rightRow--;
            break;
        case 1:
            rightCol++;
            break;
        case 2:
            rightRow++;
            break;
        case 3:
            rightCol--;
            break;
        }

        /* If left path is not the end of path then update car position */
        if (leftRow >= 0 && leftRow < rows &&
            leftCol >= 0 && leftCol < cols &&
            map[leftRow][leftCol] == ROAD)
        {
            carDirection = leftDirection;
            map[carRow][carCol] = ROAD;
            carRow = leftRow;
            carCol = leftCol;
            map[carRow][carCol] = CAR;
        }

        /* If right path is not the end of path then update car position */
        else if (rightRow >= 0 && rightRow < rows &&
                 rightCol >= 0 && rightCol < cols &&
                 map[rightRow][rightCol] == ROAD)
        {
            carDirection = rightDirection;
            map[carRow][carCol] = ROAD;
            carRow = rightRow;
            carCol = rightCol;
            map[carRow][carCol] = CAR;
        }
        else
        {
            carDirection = (carDirection + 2) % 4; /* Turn around (180 degrees) if no path is found */

            /* Handles changing direction of car when reaches the end of path. */
            switch (carDirection)
            {
            case 0:
                map[carRow][carCol] = CAR_NORTH;
                break;
            case 1:
                map[carRow][carCol] = CAR_EAST;
                break;
            case 2:
                map[carRow][carCol] = CAR_SOUTH;
                break;
            case 3:
                map[carRow][carCol] = CAR_WEST;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <map_file_name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    const char *filename = argv[1];

    loadMap(filename);
    enableBuffer();

    /* Enter game loop*/
    while (1)
    {
        printMap();
        moveCar();

        char input = getchar();
        if (input == 'q')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (input == 'u')
        {
            undoMove(); // Call undo function if 'u' is pressed
        }
        else
        {
            movePlayer(input);
        }

        if (checkWinCondition())
        {
            printf("You Win!\n");
            break;
        }

        if (checkLoseCondition())
        {
            printf("You Lose!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    disableBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        free(map[i]);
    }
    free(map);

    return 0;
}
```

I have updated the code with structs and linked list. But the output isn't as desired. The player doesn't return back to it's previous state, the car will duplicate which is incorrect. The car should work the same as player for undo feature.

Comment: Why do you want to use a generic linked list? And, can you implement a generic linked list?

Comment: It's the assignment requirement. The thing is i've tried to implement the linked list, but the player and car position had becomed a mess after using undo feature. Which is not as expected.

Comment: A linked list would be an expensive solution, allocating nodes to store each move, or pair of moves... (`malloc()` comes with its overheads.) Have you considered a large array of single bytes? The car moves first, so even numbered elements would be car motions; odd elements for 'person' movements. If, at step 100, you want to "undo", simply reset to the beginning and replay the first 98 or 99 steps without pausing... A counter and a large array... Seems simple enough... (Don't step beyond the upper boundary of the array!)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Worrying about the *cost* of memory allocations for a basic homework assignment is rather absurd - especially when it sounds like it is (or otherwise enables) a requirement for completing the task, and performance is clearly not a priority (re: `system("clear");`). Your approach is good, however, and works essentially the same for a linked list.

Comment: @user22772211 If you need help with a linked list, you need to *show* us the code with the linked list. Please try to create a [mre] that focuses on your *specific* issue. This also means removing any code not directly relating to the problem (i.e., remove anything that deals with files - hard-code your arrays, and read user input from the same hard-coded string of characters every time, instead of using standard input).

Comment: Hi guys i have updated my code. Please take a look and tell me what can i improve on. Because the output is not working as desired.

Comment: To me it's unclear what the question is! Can you add a detailed description? BTW: The two functions for add/remove to the linked list seems fine. But you should get rid of those global variables as soon as possible.

Comment: Too much code.... but it seems your `undoMove` should also change some values in `map` in order to clear potential changes made by the previous move

Comment: OT: When you load the map from the file you always do `carDirection = CAR_EAST`.  That seems strange.

Comment: Adn in `movePlayer`: Shouldn't `case 'q'` and `default` be a return instead of a `break`

Comment: Pleyse provide a few sample data cases and the corresponding output you get with the contrasting expected output. Also a full version of the assignment/requirements would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Nostalgia! Who remembers "ATC.exe" (Air Traffic Control for DOS)?

With time to kill today, here's a working re-write of your basic code, trying to trim it down somewhat. The bones of your work were a good starting point. There are a few somewhat significant changes in this code.

To begin with, the initial "map" is now printable ASCII characters for each cell signifying their meaning. (Best to move away from `scanf()` and its cousins as quickly as possible.) Here's my small "map" with '/' added to highlight full line lengths (not present in the file.)

```
10 16
/                /
/                /
/        P       /
/                /
/         C....  /
/    G        .  /
/  *          .  /
/  *          .  /
/                /
/                /
```

And, here's the extremely re-worked code (with a smattering of comments). It's only been *lightly* tested. There may be a few hiccups to be found within.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <termios.h> // disabled for development
//#include <unistd.h>

char **map; // global variables are not good; the fewer the better.
int rows, cols;
enum { north, east, south, west }; // replacing #DEFINE because they SHOUT!

char drawCar[] = { // Useful LUT (look up table) for these. Should be inside printMap()
    '^', // CAR_NORTH
    '>', // CAR_EAST
    'v', // CAR_SOUTH
    '<'  // CAR_WEST
};

typedef struct { // Simple storage of 1xRow and 1xCol
    int r, c;
} pcg; // Named for Person, Car, Goal...

typedef struct Node {
    int idx; // added for debugging output
    pcg p; // person
    pcg c; // car
    int cDir; // car's direction
    struct Node *prev; // "previous", not "next" in this 'stack/LL' implementation
} Node;

pcg goal; // Row and Col of the "Goal"

// Combine code when possible. Don't repeat yourself
void rawMode( int onOff) { // input "raw"(1) or "cooked"(0)
#if 0 // disabling raw mode
    struct termios term;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &term);
    if( onOff )
        term.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
    else
        term.c_lflag |= (ECHO | ICANON);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &term);

#else
    onOff = 0; // quiet compiler warning
#endif
}

void userGuide() { // trivial UX output. Again, don't duplicate code (or output)
    puts(
        "w - move up\n"
        "a - move left\n"
        "s - move down\n"
        "d - move right\n"
        "u - undo\n"
        "q - quit"
    );
}

void *checkedAlloc( size_t sz ) { // safe memory allocator
    void *p = calloc( 1, sz );
    if( p == NULL ) {
        perror( "Memory allocation failed" );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    return p;
}

// "InsertBlah" is ambiguous. "Push" shows LL being used as a stack
Node *push( Node *prev ) { // prepend this round onto LL
    Node *np = checkedAlloc( sizeof *np );
    if( prev ) {
        *np = *prev; // copy to set up for next round
        np->idx = (prev->idx + 1); // for debugging output
    }
    np->prev = prev;
    return np;
}

Node *undoMove( Node *np ) { // Undo last move ("Pop"???)
    if( np->prev ) { // Only if NOT at head of list (original positions)
        // Restore previous by removing the current from the linked list
        Node *del = np;
        np = np->prev;
        free( del );
    }
    return np;
}

Node *loadMap( FILE *fp ) { // load, allocate, translate map file.
    char buf[256]; // big working buffer

    fgets( buf, sizeof buf, fp ); // Doesn't leave residual '\n' to trip over later.
    sscanf( buf, "%d %d", &rows, &cols );

    // instantiate first node
    Node *n0 = push( NULL );
    n0->cDir = east; // Go East young man (for some reason...)

    // allocate and load map info, preserving player & car coords.
    map = checkedAlloc( rows * sizeof *map );
    for( int r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        map[r] = checkedAlloc( cols * sizeof *map[0] );
        fgets( buf, sizeof buf, fp ); // Should add error test/handling

        for( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ ) {
            if( r == 0 || r == rows - 1 || c == 0 || c == cols - 1 )
                map[r][c] = '*'; // borders are asterisks
            else
                switch( map[r][c] = buf[c] ) {
                    case 'G':   goal.r = r; goal.c = c; break;
                    case 'P':   map[r][c] = ' '; n0->p.r = r; n0->p.c = c; break;
                    case 'C':   map[r][c] = '.'; n0->c.r = r; n0->c.c = c; break;
                    // Notice that coords of 3 entities are stored in this node.
                    // Notice that 'P' and 'C' markers are erased from stored map
                }
        }
    }
    return n0;
}

void printMap( Node *np ) { // Output pristine map with person & car sprites showing
//  system( "clear" );
    system( "cls" ); // Windoze...

    char rowCpy[256]; // fudge... large string buffer
    for( int r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        memcpy( rowCpy, map[r], cols ); // copy of this row from map[][]
        if( r == np->c.r ) rowCpy[ np->c.c ] = drawCar[ np->cDir ]; // arrow for car
        if( r == np->p.r ) rowCpy[ np->p.c ] = 'P'; // P for person
        printf( "%.*s\n", cols, rowCpy ); // output entire row
    }
    userGuide();

    printf( "Nodes: " ); // debugging help...
    for( ; np; np = np->prev )
        printf( "%d ", np->idx );
    putchar( '\n' );
}

void newPosn( int dir, int *r, int *c ) { // helper funct to reduce code duplication
    switch( dir ) {
        case north: (*r)--; break;
        case south: (*r)++; break;
        case west: (*c)--; break;
        case east: (*c)++; break;
    }
}

int movePlayer( int dir, Node **p ) { // try to reposition person sprite
    int r = (*p)->p.r, c = (*p)->p.c;

    newPosn( dir, &r, &c ); // tentative values

    // only valid if in-range and not into an obstacle
    if( 0 < r && r < rows-1 && 0 < c && c < cols-1 && map[r][c] != '*' ) {
        *p = push( *p ); // valid, so preserve previous node
        (*p)->p.r = r; // and set this node's values for the person
        (*p)->p.c = c;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; // invalid user selection; handle gently (no consequences)
}

void moveCar( Node *p ) {
    int tryDirs[] = { 0, 1, 3, 2 }; // ahead, +90 turn, +270 turn, +180 turn
    // last resort, turning 180deg, had better work!

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof tryDirs/sizeof tryDirs[0]; i++) {
        int tDir = (p->cDir + tryDirs[i]) % 4; // try a rotation, possibly 0deg
        int r = p->c.r; // tentative values
        int c = p->c.c;

        newPosn( tDir, &r, &c ); // head in that direction??

        // Still on a road?     
        if( 0 < r && r < rows-1 && 0 < c && c < cols-1 && map[r][c] == '.' ) {
            p->c.r = r; // Preserve car's new location and direction.
            p->c.c = c;
            p->cDir = tDir;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    if( argc != 2 ) {
        printf( "Usage: %s <map_file_name>\n", argv[0] );
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" ); // Deal with argv[] in main()...
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        perror( "Error opening file" );
        return 1;
    }

    Node *head = loadMap( fp ); // initialise from file

    fclose( fp );

    rawMode( 1 );

    printMap( head );

    // game loop
    int playing = 1; // flag to control looping
    while( playing > 0 ) {
        char ch = (char)getchar();
        if( ch == '\n' ) continue; // "cooked" input for me...

        int playerMove = north; // Cascading FALLTHROUGHS below. set north == 0
        switch( ch ) {
            case 'q': // quit
                playing = -1;
                break;
            case 'u': // undo
                head = undoMove( head ); // the desired functionality
                printMap( head );
                break;
            case 'a': // west == 3
                playerMove++; // FALLTHROUGH's to increment to target value
            case 's': // south == 2
                playerMove++;
            case 'd': // east == 1
                playerMove++;
            case 'w': // north == 0
                playing += movePlayer( playerMove, &head ); // Success? playing == 2
                break;
            default:
                puts( "Invalid input..." );
                userGuide();
                break;
        }

        if( playing > 1 ) { // successful user move
            moveCar( head );

            // How nice to compare 2 pairs of int's so simply!
            if( memcmp( &head->p, &goal, sizeof(pcg) ) == 0 ) // Player reached goal
                playing = -2;
            else
            if( memcmp( &head->p, &head->c, sizeof(pcg) ) == 0 ) // collision
                playing = -3;
            else
                playing = 1; // keep playing
            printMap( head );
        }
    }

    rawMode( 0 );

    char *ended[] = { "Lost", "Won", "quit. Bye bye" };
    printf( "You %s!\n", ended[ playing + 3] );

    for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
        free( map[i] );
    free( map );
    // freeing the LL is left as an exercise
    return 0;
}
```

Possibly the most relevant change is that `map[][]` only stores *static* features. The moving person and car are *added to* the temporary output buffer and output. There's no stress involved, trying to *restore* features (like the road surface indicators).

It's filled some time adapting your code to this version. I hope it provides you with a basis for moving forward with your project (like re-writing Pacman).

Comment: Impressive effort but (at least for me) there's too much code to read and understand. Few comments from a very quick "review": 1) Still too many globals for my taste 2) `map` shouldn't be a "jagged" array. I would prefer a single allocation of a 2d array (aka array-of-array).

Comment: @SupportUkraine Agree completely. Thanks for "review"! Perhaps I'll get back to it implementing those improvements. My primary reason for this was to give the OP a working example that can demonstrate how many nodes will be created for the LL... imho, a circular queue would be better, allowing up to 'n' undo's and no more. Back to my premise that unlimited allocation of nodes is not such a great idea. (opinion.) Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: Anyway... the effort deserves some recognition....

Comment: @SupportUkraine Have been mucking with this code. OP version: ~450 lines; Above version: ~260 lines; Latest version (Windows): ~160 lines, no global variables, and a single 2D array. "Undo" (ie: history) now with array sized by parameter and a couple of `memmoves()` to push/pop. Don't want to post the code and cop the criticism "not vanilla enough!" C'est la guerre `:-)`